# How do I remove in-column line breaks?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, parsing, newline

I am parsing a CSV file to a Pandas DataFrame in Python. Due to 'extra' newlines occuring in the string, it is not possible for me to achieve a CSV-file that convertible.

f.e. a string in one of the fields is :

"R door board \n
713x396x16 \n
1/7"

This string should become "R door board 713x396x16 1/7", but **without** removing the newline characters (\n) at the end of the lines. Otherwise, the file will become one full line.

Greetings!

[Click here to view in-file example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hup5o.png)

Comment: Your question turns out to be a bit ambiguous; the field in the actual file is *not* surrounded with quotes, which it would need to be in order to be correctly parsed as CSV. And the image you pasted is almost useless -- I couldn't read it on my phone, for example. (My eyesight isn't great, but unlike some people I'm not dependent on a screen reader. A screen reader wouldn't be able to read your image at all.) This is why we strongly discourage the use of images; please edit the actual sample text as real text, inside a code block.

Answer (score 1):

With pandas, you can remove the extra new lines by simply using [**`pandas.DataFrame.replace`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) :

```
import pandas as pd

(
    pd.read_csv(r'path_to_your_original_csv')
      .replace(r'\n',' ', regex=True)
      .to_csv(r'path_to_your_new_csv')
)
```

Comment: Hi! This will remove all '\n' lines, I only want to remove the in-string '\n'-chars, but thanks for your answer!

Comment: I tested the code before posting my answer. the character `\n` in the end of lines is not removed. In the output you don't get a one line `.csv` but multi lines of strings without the extra new line.

Comment: I still have the same amount of rows as before. Are there any more characters out there that cas cause a newline when converting? (except for \n and \r)